# PHP cannot anonymously bind to LDAP

Tags: php, iis-7, ldap, bind

Problem is that I can connect LDAP through PHP but I cannot bind to it.

In Apache Directory Studio I can connect and bind without any problem but in PHP result is always "FAIL".

How to bind to LDAP with PHP?

```
<?php

$ldaphost = "ldaps://server.net";
$ldapport = 636;

$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport);

if($ldapconn){
    echo 'Connected';

    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn);


    if($ldapbind){
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "FAIL";
    }
}
```

Comment: what does ```ldap_error()``` say?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the protocol version

```
<?php

// Anonymous connection

$ldaphost = "ldaps://server.net";
$ldapport = 636;

$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
    or die("Cannot connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    echo 'Connected';

    // set protocol version
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    // anonymous identification
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn);

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo 'OK';
    } else {
        echo 'FAIL';
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Still the same. Prints "FAIL". echo $ldapbind shows that $ldapbind is empty

Comment: It worked when I used $ldaphot without "ldaps://" and with 389 port. But it's not secured connection. How to bind anonymously on secured connection?

Comment: Can you display the extended error?
<pre>
        if (ldap_get_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $extended_error)) {
                echo "Error Binding to LDAP: $extended_error";
            } else {
                echo "Error Binding to LDAP: No additional information is available.";
            }
<code>

Comment: Error Binding to LDAP: No additional information is available

Comment: I'm out of idea. Even if it is strange to do an anonymous connection on a SSL (ldaps) service, I hope that someone else might help you.